# PostGIS TIGER Geocoder data source

Tags: geocoding, postgis, tiger-lines

I am configuring PostGIS TIGER Geocoder and looking for alternative source of TIGER files, at least for one or more state (at the moment all government census resources are down).

Namely, these are the files needed by PostGIS Geocoder: 
TIGER2012: STATE, COUNTY, PLACE, COUSUB, TRACT, TABBLOCK, BG, ZCTA5(2010), FACES, FEATNAMES, EDGES, ADDR.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a similar question on [help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/26929/census-ftp-shutdown-tiger-data-is-anywhere-a-mirror-for-those-tiger-files) asking for a mirror and according to the answer there are at least the following two alternatives:

- https://census-backup.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html
- http://forever.codeforamerica.org/Census-API/shutdown-2013.html

The second link seems to have most (or all?) of your files.